# Android Status Bar transparent when using AppTheme.NoActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, themes, auto-generate

When I apply the auto-generated `AppTheme.NoActionBar` to my activity via `android:theme` like so:

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="mypackage">

    <application
        ...
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

My **MainActivity** is rendered with a transparent status bar at the top, which eventually has a white background, and white text over it. If the device is charging, that is the only symbol to be seen.

[image: Transparent ActionBar]

*Transparent ActionBar from AppTheme.NoActionBar*

Here is my **values/styles.xml:**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

</resources>
```

In the second style, you can see `AppTheme.NoActionBar`, which by default inherits AppTheme, however nowhere in either style specifies that the status bar should be transparent.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Chances are, if you've come across this issue, you have a folder called **values-v21** and in it a file called **styles.xml**. This file defines styling for devices using **API 21+** (**Android 5.0+**). This file will also most likely contain the following style named `AppTheme.NoActionBar`. Sound familiar?

**values-v21/styles.xml:**

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

`AppTheme.NoActionBar` was defined in the **values/styles.xml** provided in the question, which is still valid, however that file is only used for devices **under API 21**. If you look at the code, you can immediately identify the issue just by seeing the word transparent towards the very end. A little to the left and we see `statusBarColor` and voila. That's the issue. If you do not which to provide this styling for more up-to-date users you can simply **remove that line** of styling.

**values-v21/styles.xml:**

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And here's the result of that style removal:

[image: Fixed result]

*Good ol' opaque status bar*

Comment: why they do this?

Comment: @jsHate I believe it's just to introduce different styling across different generations.

Comment: Can't believe I wasted good chunk of hours trying to figure out what's the issue. Thank you!